# combine multiple controls in a uwp resourcedictionary

Tags: xaml, uwp

i would like to controltemplate a checkbox and a textbox control. i would then like to create a number of styles for those two controls and a textblock. i would like to have these in a dictionary in a separate file. the part i am having difficulty with is i want to be able to group those controls together on a container i.e. grid, and i would like to reference the grid that contains these controls in my main form. i am fully capable of working with controls and dictionaries. i simply cannot create a workflow that involves grouping. i hope to remove code clutter and create code flexibility. i'm pretty sure i am not trying to create a user control.

[image: a lot of this but label toggle input]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to be the most correct workflow:

i) create a separate xaml sheet from the new items ResourceDictionary template or add to one you've already created

ii) define the template and style for each individual control that will make up your group

iii) like we often do, define a new custom control as a separate object in its own xaml sheet--unlike a dictionary where you keep adding new components. there is a new item UserControl template

iv) drop a container object in the new UserControl, and add the components you would like, to the new user control, referencing them by defining a MergedDictionary inside of UserControl.Resources

v) place your control inside of your form layout(MainPage.xaml etc.) like you would any control by entering local: and your control name s such `<`local:CustomUserControl . . . /`>`

Why this was such a problem for me? This seems basic, but the documentation surrounding this exact content is lacking--in existence and in clarity, and I come from directX not WPF.  UserControls are root and don't go inside of a user dictionary. As far as I can tell there is in fact no way to drop a grid inside of a user dictionary, or as root inside of a file and reference that(i haven't been successful with this and I assume it has a lot to do with inheritance behind the scene.) I was hesitant to use UserControl because it seemed that there was a lot of obligation to fill in boiler plate code, but when I got all my referencing working it became clear that i could drop the sub controls in and just set the style and template in my dictionary.

If I'm missing something by all means let me know . . ..